# library not found for -lPayPalMPL

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have added and used PayPal MPL library. I can use the code but can't build the App. There is a linker error: 
"ld: library not found for -lPayPalMPL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
Does anyone know any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This issues comes when Library searchpath in build setting are missing. Just simply add its Done.

Comment: It was added but have space in it and needed to be enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

That was due to a space in Library Search Path. Simple enclose your library search path in double quotes("search_path") and its Done.